# Access virtual host on apache without host redirection?

Tags: apache, virtual, host

I have apache 2.4 installed on Ubuntu server 14.04 and have setup different virtual host like domain1.com,domain2.com,domain3.com. The web server is meant to be accessed only from local network. So I tried to edit /windows/syste32/drivers/hosts and added line like this
 `192.168.1.90 domain1.com`
and can now access the domain1 from that machine by simply putting domain1.com in browser. However I wonder if I can access specific virtual host on apache without editing the hosts file, I mean entering something like this in browser
`192.168.1.90/domain1.com`
, but this doesn't work since apache tries to retrieve content from the default host. In other words: If I know the apache server ip and virtual host domain, can I access it via browser directly?